# MapView inside ScrollView doesn't show zoom controls

Tags: android

I put a MapView inside a ScrollView.

Also, I added zoom control to the map view

```
 mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

The ScrollView scrolls correctly, but when I click on the MapView, the zoom control is not displayed. (for most of the time). Normally, the zoom control should show at botton of map view.

It seems Android confused with touch (or click) event on MapView and ScrollView.

I'd like to be able to **'focus'** the mapview, and shows the zoom control.

I've tried to disable the scrolling ability of ScrollView, but it doesn't work.

Any suggestion?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I put a MapView inside a ScrollView.

That is unlikely to work. Do not put scrollable widgets inside a `ScrollView`. `MapView` already knows how to scroll.